# How do I get a uri out of this url like this format in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, dart-http

EDIT: Adds to the issue
I need to get a uri out of this url:

https://us-central1-cam.cloudfunctions.net/create

Usually I use Uri.parse or Uri.https, but neither work (I think) because of the us-central1-cam. before the host cloudfunctions.net. Any chance there is a name for this format? Language is dart. The type the API needs is a map containing Strings or a single string if there is no path.

Here is my code:

'''

```
 onTap: () async {
                  final parameters = {
                    "response_type": "code",
                    "client_id":
                        "57",
                    "redirect_uri": {
                  Uri.encodeComponent(
                      "https://us-central1-41915.cloudfunctions.net"),
                  "/create",
                },
                    ),
                    "state": "heo5jt,9wv5jDRANCWX,kdrjghgyqw.c/w,",
                    "scope": "wallet:accounts:create,"
                        "wallet:addresses:create,"
                        "wallet:transactions:request",
                  };
                  final uri = Uri.https(
                      "www.coinbase.com", "/oauth/authorize", parameters);
                  print(uri);
                  final response = await http.get(uri);
                  print(response.body);
                },
```

'''
The error is the API won't accept it. However, this syntax works (But isn't the right page, test only): '''"redirect_uri": {
"https://1x1.photo",
"/home",
},'''

Comment: Does `URI.parse()` not work? If you post some code with an expected result, and a description as to why it doesn't work (e.g. throws an error, incorrect output, etc) it will be easier to answer the question

Comment: @cameron1024 I added everything you suggested

Comment: `Uri.https` will encode its query parameter `Map` automatically.  Your explicit call to `Uri.encodeComponent` will end up double-encoding it.